# Getting error while trying to use httpClient with rest api

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

i am getting console error while executing rest api .
error is :-
message: "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"

this.http.get("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/co").subscribe((aa) => {alert('okay')})

The url is https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/co

How to solve it ?

Comment: have you enabled CORS in rest server?

Comment: yeah it's enabled

Comment: A semicolon seems to be missing after the call to `alert()` within `subscribe` method. Is that just a typo in the question?

Comment: @akg179 Semi colon is not mandatory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not see anything wrong with this code, perhaps you are using an older Angular version? I tried this in a simple Angular 8 project and it seems to work perfectly:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'test';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.http.get('https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/alpha/co').subscribe((aa) => { alert('okay'); });
  }
}
```

When I run the project I can see in my network tab that the request has gone through and that the alert shows:

[image: working request]